# \text{} error in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

When I compile the following code:

```
\subsection{Force}
A force accelerates that standard body by exactly 
$ 1 \text{ m/s^2 } $ 
is defined to have a magnitude of 
$ 1 \text(N) $
The direction of a force is the direction of the acceleration is causes.
```

I receive this error:

```
Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.196 $ 1 \text{m/s^2}
                       $ I've inserted a begin-math/end-math symbol since I think you left one out. Proceed, with fingers crossed.

! Extra }, or forgotten $. \textdef@ ...th {#1}\let \f@size
#2\selectfont #3}
                                                  } l.196 $ 1 \text{m/s^2}
                       $ I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
```

What is going on?

Comment: You can't put math content into `\text{...}`; it's for typesetting non-math content within math mode.

Comment: The error goes if you put `\text{$m/s^2$}` but it is all wrong!

Comment: I once encountered the same problem. But I found using "\textup{}" will do. For example, it works that $\int x^{2} \textup{d}x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not be doing it that way. Use `siunitx` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[detect-all]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \subsection{Force}
A force accelerates that standard body by exactly
\SI{1}{\meter\per\second^2}
is defined to have a magnitude of
\SI{1}{\newton}.
The direction of a force is the direction of the acceleration is causes.
\end{document}
```

[image]